# How to index 2-dimensional values like x,y position in map

Tags: kotlin, indexing, data-structures

I'm developing a map in Kotlin.

When I zoom in, I need to know what place in my screen (ex: Places in 123.45<x<124.57, 63.2<y<64.5)

When I used MySql, it calculated very fast.
But I have to develop data structure myself.

For this I used 2 TreeMap each index x, y and intersect them. But it has awful performance.

What Can I do to index 2-dimensional index. And get values between each value.

Add ===========================================================

```
    // method 1: without treemap
    for (point in points){
        if(point.x in startX..finishX && point.y in startY..finishY){
            satisfiedPoints.add(point)
        }
    }

    // method 2: with treemap
    val satisfiedXPoints = xIndex.subMap(startX, true, finishX, true).values
    
    for(point in satisfiedXPoints){
        if(point.y in startY..finishY){
            satisfiedPoints.add(point)
        }
    }
```

I used TreeMap like this. But method 2 takes more time than 1. Is there something wrong with iterate map?

Comment: Can you share the code that you have, using two SortedMaps seems sensible, but can't say much without seeing what you tried.
Depending on how many matches you have it might be faster to do the second lookup inverted, so you could experiment with a HashMap<Place,y-coordinate> so you don't need to linearly go through the second map.

Comment: Size of points is 1,000,000